# How to change style of PreferenceThemeOverlay / PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme, appsettings, preferenceactivity

I worked myself thru the [AndroidFundamtentals Tutorial 09.2 (App Settings)](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-adding-settings-to-app#2) but I couldn't find a working solution for my problem.

I want to change the style (backgroundcolor) of the Settings-Fragment in my app.

That's what I have coded in the styles.xml so far:

```
    <style name="AppThemeWithActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/cr_blue_dark2</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/cr_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/cr_green</item>
<!-- more styles-->
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppTheme.SettingsScreen</item>
    </style>
    
    
    
    <style name="AppTheme.SettingsScreen" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/cr_black</item>
        <item name="background">@color/cr_black</item> <!--one of these should make the background black-->
    </style>
```

This code does not change the background color of the Settings fragment.

If you need more code just write an comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution / mistake.
The parent of the style `AppThemeWithActionBar` is wrong.
It changes the background to light.

Change the title of the style like this:

```
 <style name="AppThemeWithActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
```

Also change the theme of the activity in the `Manifest.xml` file.